# Le genre du nom « gens » en présence d'un adjectif

Tags: genre, noms

Ceci est issu de la page 34 de *Schaum's Outline of French Grammar* :

> When the adjective precedes the noun *gens*, it is feminine. When it follows, it is masculine.
>
> - les *bonnes* gens (good people)
> - les gens *agés* (old people)

Pourquoi est-ce que le nom masculin pluriel *gens* se comporte de la sorte ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Le mot **gens** était féminin en ancien français (de par sa racine latine qui était féminine) et ce n'est qu'au XIII<sup>e</sup> qu'on a commencé à l'employer aussi au masculin.

De nos jours on l'emploie encore au féminin quand il est immédiatement précédé d'un adjectif à forme féminine distincte et qu'il n'est pas suivi d'un complément.

- [Les petites gens](http://www.actualitte.com/critiques-bd/les-petites-gens-leurs-petites-vies-de-tristesse-et-de-tendresse-1944.htm)
- « Les vieilles gens, tenaces aux vieux mots,… »  (V.Hugo – *Les Misérables*)
- « Chez les bonnes gens, la    vie est aussi plate qu'un court de tennis. » (Frédéric Dard – *Réflexions jubilatoires sur l’existence*)

Exemples trouvés dans Grevisse :
*Quelles honnêtes et bonnes gens* ! mais *Quels bons et honnêtes gens !* puisque *bon* n'est pas placé immédiatement avant *gens* et que *honnête* est un adjectif qui a la même forme au masculin et au féminin.

Grevisse a trois pages sur le sujet… mais on pourra [télécharger cet article](http://platea.pntic.mec.es/~cvera/hotpot/gens.pdf) qui me semble un récapitulatif accessible.

Answer (score 0):

The expression "les bonnes gens" is an exception to the gender of "gens" which is usually masculine.

It's quite an old expression too, so for common french conversation, "gens" will almost always be masculine. As the Schaum's says, though, when the adjective is in front of the word, it becomes feminine.

To be honest, I can't think of any other expression that uses 'gens' as a feminine. Those are minor exceptions and certainly not usual in french.
Most words only have one gender and stick to it.

Comment: Je vous suis reconnaissant et ai plussoyé.