# The grammar of "gens"

Tags: grammaire

Its grammar has been explained in *Le Petit Grevisse* book but I can't get it.
What would be the gender of the adjectives that come with "gens" in these specific  sentences that have been shown in the book and why?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Le genre du nom « gens » en présence d'un adjectif](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8268/le-genre-du-nom-gens-en-pr%c3%a9sence-dun-adjectif)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm just gonna translate in my own words what Grevisse said.

> *Gens* is masculine in most cases.
> The exception is: if it is preceded by a word that has a different spelling whether it is conjugated in masculine or feminine (e.g. *bon* is masculine, *bonne* is feminine, while *honnête* is both masculine and feminine), then whatever comes before is conjugated in feminine, but whatever comes after stays in the masculine form.

So, for example, we say:

> *Toutes les vieilles gens.*

Because *vieux / vielle* is an adjectif that takes different spelling whether it is conjugated in masculine or feminine form.

But, we say:

> *Quels bons et honnêtes gens.*

Because what immediately precedes *gens* is an adjective that is written the same way in both gender, *honnête*, so *gens* stays in the masculine form. If the adjective *bon* was immediatly before *gens*, then it would have been in the feminine form.

Hope it's clearer to you now!